# Replace character if list index is out of range

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
['21 25 5', '16 20 16', '16 20 12', '7 10 2', '2 3  1 ', '2 3   ', '']
```

And I want to print every third items like this:

```
['5', '16', '12', '2', '1', '']
```

But the last item is causing a index list out of range due to the empty string.
What I want is to replace all empty strings by a `0`

So the result I would like to have is this:

```
['5', '16', '12', '2', '1', '0']
```

I don't know how to do that. Here is a piece of what I am trying to do:

```
carac_list = ['21 25 5', '16 20 16', '16 20 12', '7 10 2', '2 3  1 ', '2 3   ', '']
actual = [item.split()[2] for item in carac_list]

print("Actual = " + str(actual))
```

Comment: why just one 0 and not two - from `'2 3   '` and from `''`?

Comment: Yes, it could be two 0, the last empty list is somthing i have to remove, my idea is that if the thrid character is empty the the lists is to replace it by a 0 or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> seq
['21 25 5', '16 20 16', '16 20 12', '7 10 2', '2 3  1 ', '2 3   ', '']
>>> [i[0] if i else '0' for i in (i.split()[2:] for i in seq)]
['5', '16', '12', '2', '1', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Assignment Expressions/walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) introduced in Python3.8

```
carac_list = ['21 25 5', '16 20 16', '16 20 12', '7 10 2', '2 3  1 ', '2 3   ', '']
actual = [y[2] if len(y) == 3 else '0' for item in carac_list if (y := item.split())]
print(actual)
```

Out:

```
['5', '16', '12', '2', '1', '0']
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to some others but with a single `if` and a single `for` in the list comprehension, using the Walrus operator in Python 3.8+

```
carac_list = ['21 25 5', '16 20 16', '16 20 12', '7 10 2', '2 3  1 ', '2 3   ', '']
out = [y[2] if len(y := x.split()) >= 3 else "0" for x in carac_list]

['5', '16', '12', '2', '1', '0', '0']
```